# is there a way to replace a new line with sed?

Tags: regex, sed

I have this text.

```
Code=200]:[ (381_3544|null|https_//cdn10.connected-stories.com)(
             Penn State World Campus  - San Deigo
        |TV)]:677:01:SUCCESS
20220929010707:[url=https_//rtr.innovid.com/r1.62b49edb185030.50315160;cb=1372882909, breakId=1
```

I want to remove a new line \n end of "(" and "Deigo"
Example:

```
Code=200]:[ (381_3544|null|https_//cdn10.connected-stories.com)(Penn State World Campus  - San Deigo|TV)]:677:01:SUCCESS
20220929010707:[url=https_//rtr.innovid.com/r1.62b49edb185030.50315160;cb=1372882909, breakId=1
```

I tried using this command.

> sed -ie "s/San Deigo\n/San Deigo/g"

It is not working. I also tried -z option but it deleted all the line and append to the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples please try following GNU `awk`. Written and tested with shown samples only.

```bash
awk -v RS='\n[0-9]{14}:\\[url=https?_' '
FNR==1{
  gsub(/\n/,"")
  printf("%s%s",$0,RT)
}
END{
  printf("%s",$0,"")
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;N;s/((\()|(Deigo))\n +/\2\3/;ba' input_file
Code=200]:[ (381_3544|null|https_//cdn10.connected-stories.com)(Penn State World Campus  - San Deigo|TV)]:677:01:SUCCESS
20220929010707:[url=https_//rtr.innovid.com/r1.62b49edb185030.50315160;cb=1372882909, breakId=1
```

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```bash
perl -pe 'chomp if /\($|San Deigo$/'
```

This will only remove the newline character. To also remove starting whitespace of lines being joined:

```bash
perl -pe 's/^\s+// if $c==$.; if(/\($|San Deigo$/){$c=$.+1; chomp}'
```

Use `perl -i` for inplace editing.

Also, don't use `sed -ie`, it will create a backup file of the original with `e` appended to the name (unless that's what you wanted).

Answer (score 1):

`sed` by default processes one line at a time; but you can join more than one line into the pattern space and then replace it.

```
sed -e '/San Deigo$/N;s/\n//' file
```

If you want to learn `sed`, probably spend half an hour reading an introduction to its facilities. The [Stack Overflow `sed` tag info page](/tags/sed/info) has links to resources.

Generally, though, perhaps you are better off using a language which is not write-only.

```
awk '/San Deigo$/ { printf "%s", $0; next }1' file
```

Awk out of the box does not have the `-i` flag which is supported by many `sed` variants (though it's not standard POSIX); GNU Awk has a `-i inplace` plug-in but then you need to make sure your Awk is `gawk`.

Comment: Thank you. Could you explain what does '$/N' do ?

Comment: `$` is part of the regex and `N` is the `sed` command to read the next line into the pattern space. Again, I'd urge you to read an introduction to `sed` rather than ask basic questions as you discover them.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/((\(|Deigo))\n/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Append the next line to the pattern space.

If the first line in the pattern space ends in `(` or `Deigo` followed by a newline, remove the new line and go again by jumping to the label `:a`.

Othewise, print/delete the first line in the pattern space and repeat.

N.B. The `D` command deletes upto and including the first newline or if there is no newline, deletes the entire line. Unlike the `d` command it alters the sed cycle in that if there had been a newline it does not read the next line but begins the cycle as if it had and continues with the remnants of the pattern space from the previous cycle.